# Pyramid: why can't I use an authentication policy without an authorization policy?

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, pyramid

Just like the title says: why can't I use an authentication policy without an authorization policy?

Setting just an authentication policy results in:

```
pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationExecutionError: <class 'pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationError'>:
    Cannot configure an authentication policy without also configuring
    an authorization policy (use the set_authorization_policy method)
```

Obviously it *usually* makes sense to specify both policies… But why does Pyramid *force* you to specify both?

My (possibly naive?) motivation for specifying only an authentication policy is that, for now, I'd like to handle authorization "manually", without involving Pyramid's authorization "stuff".

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a convincing reason why an authorization policy is required. All I can say is that it's worth attempting to fit the system into either the `ACLAuthorizationPolicy` or building a custom one. If you're dead set on not going this way, just add the acl policy and don't worry about it. Policies are very lazy and only ever invoked if you use permissions on views or via `has_permission` calls.

Comment: There isn't a good reason, but Pyramid itself doesn't use the authentication policy except in the authorization policy. Like Michael says, there is no runtime penalty for using `ACLAuthorizationPolicy()` just to make Pyramid happy and then doing everything manually which I assume means "check permission at the top of the view" from then on.